# System Volume Information folder on D drive... But System Protection not enabled for that drive?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, storage, windows-8.1

I'm running Windows 8.1, and have a 240GB SSD for my C drive and a 2TB HDD for a D drive.

On the D drive, there is a `System Volume Information` folder taking up 380GB... I'd like to reduce or eliminate this.  My understanding is that this is where System Restore information is located, but:

1. Windows reports that protection is off for that drive, and;
2. Windows reports current disk space usage for system protection is 1.23GB.

What else could this folder be for? Using Treesize Professional, I can see that it contains about 25 or so files with names like `{95cdd416-1f00-11e3-9d97-c86000bd4dd9}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}` ranging in size from 92GB to about 240MB, as well as `tracking.log` and `IndexerVolumeGuid` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that lots of the files contained in this folder predated my Windows 8 install, but I couldn't delete them in Windows no matter how much I tried.  I took ownership, changed their permissions with CACLS, no dice.

I booted a Linux Mint Live CD, and was able to delete them from there.  Voila, 300GB or so of HDD space freed.

Answer (score 2):

Shadow Copy and Indexing information, usually.

See this document for more [info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/20/55764.aspx)

Comment: And how do I manage its space usage?

Comment: Here you go: [For Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Turn-System-Restore-on-or-off)

Comment: As I said above, System Restore wasn't enabled for that drive.

Comment: In that tutorial, there was a "delete" option, which would have been a quick fix.

Comment: No it wouldn't have.  As I said, this was from the previous Windows 7 install (I only formatted the SSD), so I can all but guarantee that Windows wasn't even aware those files existed.